# Is the following procedure correct to obtain p-values and R-squared for elastic-net?

Tags: p-value, r-squared, elastic-net

Consider a dataset, denoting `X` the predictors, and `y` the response variable. To obtain p-values and R-squared for elastic-net (`EN`), I propose to do the following:

- Split my data into 80% training `TRAIN` and 20% testing `TEST` datasets
- Do 10-fold cross-validation on `TRAIN` to get the best parameters (`alpha` and `lambda`) and beta coefficients of the `ENmodel`
- Evaluate R-squared on the `TEST` dataset from:

*Pseudo-code*

```
pred.y = bestENmodel.predict(TEST.X)
SS.total = sum((TEST.y - mean(TEST.y))^2)
SS.residual = sum((TEST.y - pred.y)^2)
SS.regression = sum((pred.y - mean(TEST.y))^2)
SS.total = SS.regression + SS.residual
R.squared = 1 - SS.residual/SS.total
```

- Get p-values following the sample-splitting procedure outlined in [this paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1214/15-STS527), by (re)fitting an ordinary least square model (`OLS`) in `TEST` to the variables with non-zero beta coefficients from `bestENmodel`

*Pseudo-code*

```
OLSmodel.fit(TEST.y = <non-zero variables bestENmodel>, data=TEST.X)
```

- Possibly repeating this procedure via bootstrapping, randomly splitting the data into `TRAIN` and `TEST` datasets, in order to obtain a distribution of R-squared and p-values, as suggested in the paper mentioned above (to avoid the "p-value lottery" issue). The "final" R-squared and p-values could be the median of the respective distributions for example.

Would this procedure be correct? If not how to make it so? And if it is, could it be improved?

Any suggestion in R would be more than welcome but I am not sure it is "allowed" as my [previous post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/292371/in-r-how-to-obtain-test-data-p-values-from-linear-model-beta-coefficients-obtai) was flagged as off-topic, apparently because I presented my question in R.